# Understanding battery voltage detection circuit

Tags: mosfet, resistors, voltage-divider, battery-operated

I am looking for some battery voltage monitoring circuit and came across this one (I don't have reference now, will add once I get it.)

[image]

It uses complementary MOSFET pair [DMC2400UV](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMC2400UV.pdf) to enable the circuit and then one can read the voltage through voltage divider which lowers the voltage.

I don't understand how the resistor values are calculated in this circuit (all R1, R2, R3 & R4.) I have a Li-Po battery through which I want to measure the battery voltage. The battery voltage will  range from 4.2 - 2.7. The microcontroller connected operates on 3.3V and will be using a 12 bit ADC. I want to sense the voltage for a small time and turn off the MOSFET to reduce the current drain.

It is a battery operated device, so I want to keep current consumption to a minimum and extend its battery life.

Can you please help me in calculating the resistor values and whether this circuit will work for my case or not?

Comment: When battery is at 2.70 to 3.29 volts, how can the MCU work at 3.3 volts?

Comment: R1 and R2 just keep the MOSFET gates from floating. The value is chosen to keep the current under control. R3 and R4 are a voltage divider. Divide the voltage into whatever you want to. The only thing to keep in mind is that you will probably need to make sure that the input is low enough impedance that the ADC does not load it down or set the sampling portion of the read to a long time.

Comment: @Andyaka I didn't mention it clearly, apologies for the same. There is a cutoff in power supply once the voltage reaches below 3.4 volts as some peripherals don't work below that voltage as expected. So the device is non operable below 3.4V.

Comment: R3 and R4 are a potential divider and they are chosen to entirely suit the ADC input on your MCU and its input voltage range. The two 1M resistors are just standard pull-up/downs. Those MOSFETs look good for your range of voltages it seems.

Comment: Thanks vini_i and Andyaka for your valuable inputs. "Make sure that the input is low enough impedance" this was a valuable feedback I got along with the answer. Can you all please post it as an answer so that I can accept and close this?